# StringComparison not working while querying in CosmosDB

Tags: linq, azure-cosmosdb

Getting below error while querying the cosmosdb using stringcomparison

```
{
    "errorCode": "DocumentQueryException",
    "errorMessage": "Query expression is invalid, expression return type System.Int32 is unsupported. Query must evaluate to IEnumerable."
}
```

My code is something like below:

```
await repo.WhereAsync(something => something.Name.Equals("something", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

and whereasync implementation is something like below:

```
public async Task<IQueryable<T>> WhereAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, FeedOptions feedOptions = null)
        {
            return _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>((await _collection).DocumentsLink, feedOptions)
                .Where(predicate);
        }
```

Comment: Are you using [cosmosdb-repo](https://github.com/Crokus/cosmosdb-repo) ? If so I would suggest you move to [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut). It can handle this type of StringComparison query with the ToListAsync method.

Comment: @Elfocrash That I can achieve here as well using AsEnumerable, but I want to keep it wrapped around in Task to make it awaitable